# Grunt livereload breaks when adding directive to AngularJS app (generated with Yeoman)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, livereload

I have an AngularJS app, generated with Yeoman, with all addons enabled (such as Bootstrap, SASS...).

**Livereload was working fine, until i added a directive.** I put it in the directory /app/scipts/directives/myDirectives.js.

This is the content of **myDirectives.js:**

```
app.directive('setGroupName', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'views/setGroupName.html'
    };
});
```

Regardless of whether or not I use the setGroupName directive anywhere, simply including the file in my index.html like so

```
<script src="scripts/directives/myDirectives.js"/>
```

causes Grunt's livereload to stop working.

**PS:** Using the directive works (when it is included). I use the set-group-name directive in createGroup.html (like shown below) and the contents of setGroupName.html are displayed.

```
<div set-group-name></div>
```

**Setup:**
I have not edited the gruntfile, so anything not mentioned here I believe is standard for the

```
$ yo angular
```

setup, generating it with all addons enabled.

**Is there something wrong in the myDirectives file? Or it's location?**

Answer (score 0):

Grunt livereload breaks because of this line

```
<script src="scripts/directives/myDirectives.js"/>
```

changing it to

```
<script src="scripts/directives/myDirectives.js"></script>
```

fixes it!

Noob mistake, I guess, and not related to directives.